# Responsive navigation menu elements backwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

Greetings and salutations everybody,

The top menu of this double stack navigation displays results backwards. I tried styling

```
<li>'s
```

individually and either it did not work or I did it wrong. I also pulled out lots of hair but that didn't work either. :D Could anyone shed some light please? Many thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--From secondary Nav - find out what this does-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body {margin:0;}
ul.PrimaryNav {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#000;text-transform:uppercase;}
ul.PrimaryNav li {float:right;color:#FFFFFF;}
ul.PrimaryNav li a {display:inline-block;color:#FFFFFF;;text-align:center;padding:20px 20px;text-decoration:none;transition:0.3s;font-size:17px;}
ul.PrimaryNav li a:hover {background-color:#111;color:#FFFFFF;}
ul.PrimaryNav li.icon {display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
ul.PrimaryNav li:not(:first-child) {display:none;}
ul.PrimaryNav li.icon {float:right;display:inline-block;}

ul.PrimaryNav.responsive {position:relative;}
ul.PrimaryNav.responsive li.icon {position:absolute;right:0;top:0;}
ul.PrimaryNav.responsive li {float:none;display:inline;}
ul.PrimaryNav.responsive li a {display:block;text-align:left;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:680px) {
ul.PrimaryNav {width:100%; float:right;}
}

ul.secondaryNav {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#CC0000;text-transform:uppercase;}
ul.secondaryNav li {float:left;}
ul.secondaryNav li a {display:block;color:white;text-align:center;padding:14px 16px;text-decoration:none;}
ul.secondaryNav li a:hover:not(.active) {color:#FFFF00;}
ul.secondaryNav li a.active {background-color:#CC0000;}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:680px) {
ul.secondaryNav li {float:left;width:100%;border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;-moz-border-radius:0px 0px 0px 0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}
}

@media screen and (min-width:680px) {
ul.secondaryNav {border-radius:0px 0px 10px 0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 0px;-moz-border-radius:0px 0px 10px 0px;width:680px;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="PrimaryNav">
<li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="#home" role="navigation">Home ICON</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Solutions</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Results</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Create Wealth</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">Charity</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="secondaryNav">
<li><a href="#home">Design &amp; Build</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">Digital Marketing</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Measurement &amp; Improvement</a></li>
</ul>


<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("PrimaryNav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be because you are floating each li right - you should only apply the float to the ul (to force it to the right of the screen) not to each li in that ul:

```
ul.PrimaryNav li {float:right;color:#FFFFFF;}
```

should be

```
ul.PrimaryNav {float:right;....
ul.PrimaryNav li {color:#FFFFFF;}
```

This will cause the entire ul to be displayed to the right of the screen, but each li within it will be displayed according to the order in which you have them listed. You will also need to check the rest of the code for conflicting float:right behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I tried that before and it just expands the menu down the page.. I also can't use:

    ul.PrimaryNav li a {float:right;

as it scatters menu elements on smaller screens. Tried using display and width:100%, but still no luck. What are your thoughts please? Thanks again!

Comment: That would seem like the obvious answer but doesn't fix it... floating left simply separates the top nav to the left of the second nav on smaller screen. This might take putting into a file to test.. thanks, hopeful!

Comment: ok - first thing to note is that even though the list goes down the page - it is in the right order. Then you need to look at why its going down the page - thats because you have display:inline-block on those li's. If you change that to display:inline then it will disaply on one line - then you have to float the ul right. hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply though I think I haven't understood.. I changed:

    ul.PrimaryNav {list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#000;}
    ul.PrimaryNav li {float:right;color:#FFFFFF;}

to:

    ul.PrimaryNav {float:right;list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#000;}
    ul.PrimaryNav li {color:#FFFFFF; display:inline;}

but still it's not working.. The top menu fully floats to the left which makes no sense at all... any help would be appreciated.. many thanks again..

Comment: sorry got cut off earlier - had to go to work. will look at later and post a better answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! That will be great :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to ask again, I uploaded it to photo-gallery-website.com and floated it right successfully but now the menu squashes on responsive (small screen). In inspect element mode, it shows as "there" when I hover over the HTML but it's invisible blocks appearing.. do you have any idea please?